# Angular 7 - Display image with orientation in img tag

Tags: angular7, orientation

When showing an image in img tag it always show the original orientation. I want to show the rotated image with the exactly orientation, here is my code when binding source using angular property:

```
<img [src]="imageSrc">
```

Here is my image when view in Windows Explorer 
[image]

And here is the image on my site 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens since original orientation of image is not as we see in image viewer. Check images original orientation.

try with adding this to your css file

```
img {
    image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

[image orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation)